# VBA pivot table formatting based on field hierarchy

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I was tasked at work to write a macro that copies and formats a preliminary pivot table to fit the company wide branding style.
The basic macro is complete but I am having trouble automating the formatting of the pivot fields based on their hierarchy and dependency.

The current code looks like this

```
Sub FormatHierarchy()
    'formatting Hierarchy level 1
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotSelect "'EBITDA category'[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly + xlFirstRow, True

    With Selection
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial Narrow"
            .Size = 10
            .Bold = True
        End With

        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .WrapText = True
    End With


'formatting Hierarchy level 2
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotSelect "Account[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly + xlFirstRow, True

    With Selection
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial Narrow"
            .Size = 10
            .Bold = False
        End With

        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .WrapText = True
        .IndentLevel = 0
    End With

'formatting Hierarchy level 3
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotSelect "SuSa account[All]", _
    xlLabelOnly + xlFirstRow, True

    With Selection
        With .Font
            .Name = "Arial Narrow"
            .Size = 10
            .Bold = False
        End With

        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .WrapText = True
        .IndentLevel = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

"EBITDA category", "Account" and "SuSa account" will change based on the raw data and whatever the manager decides to call them, so I cannot directly use the names. 
Is there a way to directly reference the field names based on their hierarchy?

[original pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfqky.png)
[resulting pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3VNz.png) (bold is level 1, normal is level 2 and indented is level 3)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been 100% successful in recreating your setup, but if I understand it correctly, then the following should help:

1. Write function that cycles through each PivotFields (similar to PivotSelect, but using Index instead of name as reference).
2. Use "Position" property of PivotField to identify level in hierarchy
3. Use IF-statement for formatting based on level identified above

Example code:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields.Count
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields(i).Position = 1 Then
    'Enter your formatting for hirearchy level 1 here
ElseIf ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields(i).Position = 2
    'Enter your formatting for hirearchy level 2 here
ElseIf ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields(i).Position = 3
    'Enter your formatting for hirearchy level 3 here
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks, however same as with @Shai Rado s code, I'm getting a run-time error 13 "type mismatch when testing the code with my pivot table.

Comment: Are you still using the `With Selection` in your formatting? If so, this will not work as the code I wrote. Instead, use: `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields(i)` and then put the rest of your formatting in that `with`-block

Comment: Still getting a run-time error at the first `If`statement

Comment: What do you get if you in the "Immediate"-window in VBA write:
`?ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Account[All]").Position`
?

Comment: Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your PivotTable Field List? (Also, apologies for the silly question, but just to be sure: You started the code in your immediate-window with a question-mark (?), right?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit    

Sub FormatHierarchy()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtFld As PivotField

' set the PivotTable object
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

' loop through all Pivot Fields in Pivot Table
For Each PvtFld In PvtTbl.PivotFields
    Select Case PvtFld.Position
        Case 1
           ' do your format here ...

        Case 2
            ' do your format here ...

        Case 3
            ' do your format here ...

    End Select    
Next PvtFld

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, however I'm getting a run-time error 13 "type mismatch" when trying to run this code and I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.

Comment: @GenTugorn at what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: while debuging it's highlighting `Case 1`